# Join multiple tikz-chains (with different lengths) into one last node at their end

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I have multiple vertical chains of different lengths (node count). I want all these chains at the end coming together into one last node.

How could I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        start chain=main going right,
        every node/.style={draw},
        every join/.style={->,red}
    ]
    \node [on chain] {One};
    \node [on chain] {Two};
    {[start branch=two going below]
        \node [on chain,join] {x};
        \node [on chain,join] {y};
    }
    \node [on chain] {Three};
    {[start branch=three going below]
        \node [on chain,join] {a};
    }
    \node [on chain] {Four};

    % join all four chains to this node (with lines/arrows)
    \node {The End};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And where should lie the note with text "The end"? Now it override the node "One" ...

Comment: Four different lines: from "One" to "The End". From "y" to "The End". From "a" to "The End". From "Four" to "The End".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: extending chains]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        start chain=main going right,
        every node/.style={draw},
        every join/.style={->,red}
    ]
    \node [on chain] {One};
    \node [on chain] {Two};
    {[start branch=two going below]
        \node [on chain,join] {x};
        \node [on chain,join] {y};
    }
    \node [on chain] {Three};
    {[start branch=three going below]
        \node [on chain,join] {a};
    }
    \node [on chain] {Four};

    % join all four chains to this node (with lines/arrows)
    \node [on chain, join, below=of main-4 |- main/two-3] {The End};
    \foreach \i in {main-1,main/two-3,main/three-2}
      \draw [every join] (\i) |- (main-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

In response to the query in comments, if you want the final node to be centred at the bottom, you can substitute a library:

```
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,calc}
```

and rely on `calc` rather than `positioning` to place the node:

```
    \node [on chain, join, below=of current bounding box.south] {The End};
```

I would not recommend the use of 'sunbeam'-type arrows in this picture but, if you really want the lines to fly with the eagles, then simply replace `|-` with `--`.

```
    \foreach \i in {main-1,main/two-3,main/three-2}
      \draw [every join] (\i) -- (main-5);
```

[image: eagle output]

Maybe this works better in your real document than in the minimal example. Although you can always move the node down, this will obviously involve adding extra space which will add no value in terms of information. So, unless there's a special reason to do so (e.g. your diagram represents eagles' flight paths), it seems an easier, but less elegant, option.

[And, since sunbeams are composed of photons, we all know that they do not really behave like this at the quantum level. But I'm assuming you are concerned with sunbeams only at the macro level and so want eagles.]

Comment: "The End" should be below centered. All chains should point directly to "The End". Like sun beams ;) Your solution points to interesting tikz-technics. But I don't understand it completly. e..g What does the `|-` mean there?

Comment: It means go-down(up)-then-right(left) rather than straight there. If you change it to `--`, you will get your sunbeams. And you can adjust the positioning of the node as you wish. However, if you have it in the centre, the line from 'One' is going to cross 'y', isn't it? Generally, people don't want that. Or you can move the final node further down, but then you'll have a lot of vertical space, I guess. I think you just have to play around with it and see. Your question wasn't very specific ;). Sunbeams are easier, though, so you should be fine.

Comment: Maybe `below right=of main/two-3` - try it and see.

Comment: OK. I guess I'd use `calc` rather than `positioning` here. But the result is a mess in the MWE, at least.